# Telerik PdfFormatProvider not exporting bold text (XLSX to PDF) in .net core

Tags: pdf, .net-core, telerik, xlsx, epplus

I'm using Telerik library to generate a PDF file from an XLSX template file, in which I write the model values into specified cells.
During the compilation phase, in some cases I have to set a cell as bold, but when I generate the PDF file, the cell value is not bold.
If I set other styles, such as background color or foreground color, I see these settings in the generated PDF file.

Does anyone know why this happens?

In the Telerik documentation, in the feature section, the Bold property is supported.

To write values into the Excel template, I'm using Epplus 7.0.2 and I set the bold style in this way `cell.Style.Font.Bold = true;`

Comment: Unfortunately, it's different from my situation :(
About your first message, could it work by converting the xlsx file to html and then html to pdf? If the bold is set with <b></b> could it work?

Comment: Since the XLSX template has Thaoma as font family, I have to add embedded font into the PDF in order to see the bold text. did I get i right? 
I look at the font documentation page of Telerik PdfFormatProvider [link](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/document-processing/libraries/radpdfprocessing/concepts/fonts) and it seems that Tahoma is supported by default. As the Arial font family that I've already tested

Answer (score 0):

Unlike the .NET Framework one, RadPdfProcessing’s .NET Standard version does not offer a default mechanism to read fonts. The FixedExtensibilityManager class is exposed to help implement this functionality. It is necessary to create a custom implementation of the FontsProviderBase and properly specify the path to the respective font file: [Setting and Exporting Fonts](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/document-processing/libraries/radpdfprocessing/cross-platform/fonts)

A similar approach is used in the KB article demonstrating how to implement our own FontsProviderBase and ensure that the Calibri font is returned with the respective path to the .ttf file on the local machine.Note that a similar approach should be used for the other fonts available in the document: [How to implement FontsProvider](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/document-processing/knowledge-base/pdfprocessing-implement-fontsprovider)